# Struggling to reword this sentence

Tags: word-choice

I work for a holiday company and creating an email that gets sent to people who have booked their holiday. It basically is asking them to book "extras" to their holiday. The thing is, some people may have booked these already and it's very hard to take these people out of this big email list. So I've decided I'll keep people in there who HAVE booked their extras and those who HAVEN'T as well. I don't want people who have booked their extras to then think they haven't when they receive this email so I need to word it carefully.

I know what I want to say but don't know how to write it well. I wanted to say something along the lines of:

" If you're already booked these, then don't worry. "

Comment: May be migrated to [writers.se]

Comment: 'If you _have_ already booked', not _are_.

Comment: 'If you're happy that you have already booked all the extras you'll want, please disregard the following (and marks for proficiency!)'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's seeking writing advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's seeking writing advice. Better fit on Writing.SE.

Answer (score 1):

"If you have already booked it, then don't worry" Use this if you are saying it to a person

"If you have already booked these, then don't worry" Use this if you are showing it to a person

Comment: Why the distinction? By *showing* do you mean writing or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something simple like:

> If you've already booked your holiday, please disregard this
>   message/email.

It's always recommended to use a simple and clear language to avoid any misunderstanding. Styling your text properly also plays a significant role in getting the right kind of message through. So I'd put the above quote in the beginning of my email and style it so it pops out, e.g. using bold font, a different color or put it some kind of bordered text box so it's obvious. This way people who have already booked a holiday will notice it right away and simply move on.